# Android bits to sound converter

Tags: android, audio, converters

Exists library for android which converts bits to sound? For example, we have number as BigInteger. This number is converted to bytes and then this bytes are presented as short sound with different frequency (the best - ultra sounds). Of course, working in the opposite way would be great. Microphone get sound and converts it to bits.

Did anybody hear something about this kind of library?

Comment: Do you know the number of bytes needed to produce even a very short sound? A typical encoding takes 176000 bytes for a single second! How many bytes in a BigInteger?

Comment: I need just to send simple data like short texts, certificates, keys. At the beginning I want to send for example BigInteger which has few hundred bytes.